# Validate an ubercart checkout pane?

Tags: ubercart

I'm using the [uc_ddate module](http://drupal.org/project/uc_ddate).

How would one hook into the checkout pane to cause it to force it to validate and make the delivery date option required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would that checkout pane still be captured by hook_alter_form()?  If so you could add #required to the field there. Let me have a quick try and I'll get back to you.

EDIT: OK, this worked for me:

```
function tools_utilities_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'uc_cart_checkout_form') {
    // Make delivery date required
   $form['panes']['ddate']['ddate']['#required'] = true;
 }
}
```

Create your own module (mine is called tools_utilities in this example) and implement the above and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Thank you! That works brilliantly. I forgot it counts as a form.